# Spring Boot Admin 2 getting Actuator endpoints 401

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I have created Spring Boot Admin 2 Server and integrated Spring Boot Admin 2 Client in my API service application. Currently my API service project is protected with OAuth2 Framework. In order to bypass the actuator endpoints I have added the configuration in `WebSecurity` and `HttpSecurity` of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class, but it looks like still the actuator endpoints are giving 401. When I looked into the issue I found that in `public void configure(HttpSecurity http)` when I remove  `.antMatcher("/user")` the actuator endpoints was opened and the Admin Server was able to get all the details, but when I remove `.antMatcher("/user")` OAuth2 was not failing.

My Spring Boot Admin Server is running under `http://localhost:8080` and the API project (Admin Client) is running under `http://localhost:8081`

I am using

**Spring Boot 2 (2.0.4.RELEASE)**
**Spring Cloud (Finchley.RELEASE)**
**Spring Boot Admin 2 (2.0.2)**

Oauth2 user-info-uri is configured in my API project like as shown below

```
security: 
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:9999/auth/user
```

Some of the properties which I have added in API project is given below

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,auditevents,metrics,loggers,logfile,httptrace,env,flyway,liquidbase,shutdown,mappings,scheduledtasks,threaddump,heapdump
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.security.enabled=false
management.health.rabbit.enabled=false
spring.boot.admin.client.url[0]=http://localhost:8080
spring.boot.admin.client.username=user
spring.boot.admin.client.password=password
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.management-url=http://localhost:8081/actuator
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.health-url=http://localhost:8081/actuator/health
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-url=http://localhost:8081
```

My Custom WebSecurityConfigurer  is given below

```
@Order(1)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public WebSecurityConfigurer() {
        super(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
         web.ignoring()
         .antMatchers("/actuator/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**", "/actuator/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().and().antMatcher("/user").authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).permitAll().
         antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll().
         anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .ignoringAntMatchers("/instances", "/actuator/**");
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: did you got the answer. If Yes please post. I am also stuck on same.